# C# nth-child logic test

Tags: c#, css, dom

I've been working on my own, headless browser implementation and I feel like I am making a mess of my nth-child selector logic.  Given an element and it's 0-based position in its group of siblings is there a simple, one-line expression to see if that element belongs in the result set?

```
   public bool Evaluate(HTMLElement element)
   {
        if (element.parentNode == element.ownerDocument)
            return false;

        List<Element> children = element.Parent.Children
            .Where(e => e is Element)
            .Cast<Element>()
            .ToList();
        int index = children.IndexOf(element);
        bool result = (an + b test here);
        return result;
   }
```

Currently I have a convoluted set of branching logic based on tests for 0 values for (a) and (b) and I suspect I am making it more complicated than it needs to be.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I'm understanding correctly, you need to determine whether an `n` exists such that `index` = `a*n + b` for some fixed `a`, `b`.

```
bool result = (a == 0) ? b == index : (Math.Abs(index - b) % Math.Abs(a)) == 0;
```

If `a` is 0, then `index` must be `b`. Otherwise, `a` must evenly divide the difference between `i` and `b`.

Naturally, if a negative value for `a` is not allowed you can skip the `Math.Abs(a)` call.

Comment: a and b are both specified or implied by any given expression (although part of my problem is that I don't know what they should default to--I was assuming 0).

http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#nth-child-pseudo

Comment: I don't think I'm following then; what's the 'result set' you refer to in the question? Aren't you evaluating an element to see whether it should be included in a set, given the selector?

Comment: Yes I am evaluating to see whether or not an element should be included in the returned NodeList based on the selector.

e.g. 
li:nth-child(2n+1), 
li:nth-child(2n), 
li-nth-child(-n+2)

Comment: Your logic seems to work for all cases where (a) is positive and provided I switch to starting with index 1 instead of 0.  Negative a values still don't provide results consistent with full-fledged browsers like Chrome.

Comment: how about 
`int eleIndex = index + 1;
 if (a == 0)
     return b == eleIndex;

 int n = (eleIndex - b) / a;
 return n >= 0 && ((eleIndex - b) % a == 0);
`
If that addresses both your issues I'll update the answer.

Comment: Hmm nope it didn't work for me.  I am fiddling with this demo tool to try and work it out in my brain: http://css-tricks.com/examples/nth-child-tester/